# Single word for "present possibility"

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose you have a fair coin. Then tossing it has two possible outcomes, both equally likely.

Before you flip the coin, these possibilities are *undecided*. These could be called *future possibilities*.

If you flip the coin without looking at the result, then the outcome is *decided*, but *unknown*. There are still two possibilities for the outcome. These could be called *present possibilities*.

I'm looking for a word or short phrase to distinguish between these two different uses of the word *possibility*.

I don't think *present possibility* and *future possibility* clearly describe this usage. *Decided possibility* seems like an oxymoron, and *undecided possibility* seems redundant.

Comment: A further thought. Before the coin has been flipped, it is not certain that it is going to be flipped, so there are three future possibilities. / I'm not sure there are better terms for what you're asking. You could try over on Maths or Philosophy SE, where less common terminology may be available.

Comment: You may call them all a predetermined destiny!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it could also land on its side. ;)

Comment: @JJJ Yes; I should have edged my bets.

Comment: Rather than looking for a word, maybe you want more of a [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) answer

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities described after a coin is tossed are **potential** until the result is observed.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/potential)

> a. possible but not yet actual b. capable of being or
>   becoming but not yet in existence; *latent*

Or *latent* [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/latent)

> Present or potential but not evident or active

Comment: I think latent works better in this context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's supposed to be a word for present possibility, not future possibility. I'm open to further suggestions.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=future+possibility%2Clatent+possibility%2Cpotential+possibility&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuture%20possibility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clatent%20possibility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpotential%20possibility%3B%2Cc0)  show that 'future possibility' is far more idiomatic than either 'latent possibility' or 'potential possibility' (neither of which I find acceptable). 'There is a latent possibility of specific and penetrating vision in ...

Comment: each individual.' (from the internet) means 'Each individual possesses the possibility of specific and penetrating vision, but it is deep in the psyche'. [latent] [possibility] not [latent possibility].

Comment: @Randy Randerson You realise that you've accepted an answer attempting to give a synonym for " 'future possibility' " [scare and exemplar-identifier quotes] rather than what your title question asks for?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The definition of latent that I saw was "existing but not yet manifest." If I've accepted an incorrect answer I can change it.

Comment: @Randy Randerson I'm essentially saying that 'latent possibility' is hardly a collocation, and would almost certainly mislead people.

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating two events that would be more clearly understood if you start by treating them separately. First, you have the tossing of the coin. There are (realistically) only two possible outcomes. Then you have the observation of the coin. From the observer’s standpoint there are also two possible outcomes.

If the system does not allow the coin to change sides between the tossing and the observation, there is no point in distinguishing between the two possibilities, i.e. you don’t need an adjective to modify *possibility*.  What you need are nouns to describe the events, which you can modify with *possible* as an adjective.

For example: Joe tossed the coin in the air, caught it in his palm and slapped it onto the back of his hand. He held his hand in place, looked up, and looked around. As Jim saw it there were *two possibilities*. If they kicked off now, they’d be giving Joe and his team the choice of ends, but maybe it didn’t matter. “Heads,” he called. Joe lifted his hand casually. Jim pointed to the goal he wanted to defend. Heads it was.

Comment: I agree that for discussing a particular case like this, it is not necessary. However the point is to have a technical term for distinguishing one class of possibilities. My intended usage is much more abstract than this.

Comment: There are many resources you can draw on for terminology. On the applied side, there is the Many Worlds Interpretation of quantum mechanics originated by Hugh Everett in the fifties. There is also the Music of Changes created by John Cage around the same time. I mention these because physicists have a need to devise experiments for testable predictions, and composers must devise works that can be played. This imposes a certain clarity on their choices of words. Beyond this, of course, there is plenty of vocabulary in the theory of random processes and in computation with Turing machines.